# Database item rankings on movable weighting

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate-functions, quartile

So I have what I believe is a pretty unique problem. I need to calculate rankings for a very large table of items (200,000ish). Their 'rank' is based off of several weighted attributes which are added together. 7 attributes on a 1-4 scale (based on their quartile 1 bottom quartile 4 top) each initially equally weighted then added together (7-28 scale). I would like to allow the users to adjust the weight of the attributes making any or all of them doubly or half as important. Which would potentially change their end ranking. 
I am looking to see if anyone has dealt a similar problem or has any ideas on where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a basic design, i would try and make your orignal items, along with their default ranking immutable.

Then, you run a script on a cron, to calculate their rank on an interval. This would be done by some algorithm of your choosing, however just as an example:

Lets say an item had the following properties
{"someRetailListing":{
"id": "1",
"price": "100000.12",
"city": "New York City",
"rooms": "4",
...
"rankCity": 4,
"rankPrice": 3,
"rankQuality": 3
}
The first time your script runs, its total rank is 20/30

Now, a user comes along, and adds his input, and you save his submission in a separate bucket (or with a type in the same bucket):
{
"type":"userRank"
"uid": 3121,
"propertyID": 1
"rankCity": 3,
"rankPrice": 1,
"rankQuality": 3
}
When you script runs, perhaps you want 50% of the rank to come from users, 50% from the default. So you can sum all the user results together, and get the average user score, then merge with yours, and then do whatever youd like pretty much.

Youd save this final result 
{
"type": "userPropertyRank",
"propertyID": 1
"rankCity": 3,
"rankPrice": 3,
"rankQuality": 3
}

Comment: Not quite sure this will work either. Example. 4 items with 3 attributes ranks equally weighted. A - B - C. The initial ranks will be stored in their own table. A = 4, B = 5, C = 2. Each user should be able to change the weights on any or all of the attributes essentially re-ranking the entire table. This however, I don't think will be very feasible or efficient. The solution I have been kicking around is storing every possible permutation of the weights each in their own table. This would be ALOT of tables however.

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure for a ranking is a sort query with variables.  You just need to incorporate user input into the ranking.

The query looks something like this:

```
select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
from (select t.*, (@v1 * col1 + @v2 * col2 . . .) as ranking
      from table t
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by ranking;
```

You can readily do this in the database; you just need to pass in the right variables.

Comment: However, I don't think this wouldn't take into account of where the item ranks in comparison too all of the items because the rank for every time would have to be ran thru the new weights to calculate the correct rank order for the entire table.

Comment: @JoshSells . . . I have no idea what your comment means in the context of your question.  Your question is about getting the rankings for all the rows of a table using a particular formula.  That is what this answer does.

Comment: I don't think this will be very efficient. If every user has to run this query, which they will alot, against a very large dataset I know there will be issues.

Comment: @JoshSells . . . We can only answer the question that you asked, and that is not the question you asked.  If you have concerns about large numbers of users and particularly queries, then *ask another question*.  Editing this one would invalidate the current answers, which is rude because such edits draw downvotes.